# How to change database connection dynamically in laravel-octane?

Tags: laravel, swoole, laravel-octane, openswoole

I need to change database dynamically on the fly in laravel-octane or laravel-swoole package.
I am working on a custom multi tenant system. Application is working fine without swoole/octane.